# Formatting Dates (International and American in Same Column)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am struggling with formatting dates in Excel and am looking for some help.

I have two different date formats in the same column:
MM/DD/YYYY
DD/MM/YY

[image]

I am struggling to change the DD/MM/YY to MM/DD/YYYY. I have tried so many things and can't get it to work.

```
Public Function dateguesser(inDate As String) As Date
    dateguesser = CDate(Split(Split(inDate, " ")(0), ",")(0)) 
End Function
```

Things I have tried:

1. This solution ends up thinking that the DD in the DD/MM/YY format is the year because the year is not stored as four digits.
2. Tried to change MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YY and then convert all of them to MM/DD/YYYY.
3. Text to columns

Comment: What's the values in both types of cells? String, Date? Also, how would you determine which ones need to be manipulated (i.e. in rows 4 and 5)?

Comment: Hello, so the dates in MM/DD/YYYY format are stored as Date. The dates in DD/MM/YY format are stored as general. I have tried converting everything to general which converts the MM/DD/YYYY to values, then trying to find a solution to convert the remaining DD/MM/YY values but had no luck.

Comment: The ones that need to be manipulated are those stored as general and in the format DD/MM/YY - all others are perfect, they are stored as custom dates MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: `General` is a formating type, not a value. Is it a string or numeric value? To test, what happens if you reference a cell and add 1?

Comment: **How did the dates get there?**. If they came from a CSV or Text file, then you need to go back to that file and **import** it properly, defining the date format of that file at the time of import.

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY stored as numeric. DD/MM/YY stored as a string. When I multiply x 1 I get #VALUE!

Comment: If the dates came from a CSV file, then the ones that you claim are ***perfect*** are probably an **incorrect** date.  eg. `06/04/2021` in your workbook represents `4-Jun-2021` but in the CSV file represents `6-Apr-2021`.  Change the formatting so as to be unambiguous, and then check to see what the source really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this formula starting in B3, I think it should work for all values?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A3),A3,DATE(2000+RIGHT(A3,2),MID(A3,4,2)+0,LEFT(A3,2)+0))
```

You could also probably modify your custom function to something like this:

```
Public Function dateguesser(inDate As Variant) As Date
   If IsNumeric(inDate) Then
      dateguesser = inDate
   Else

    dateguesser = CDate(Split(Split(inDate, " ")(0), ",")(0))
   End If
   
End Function
```

Comment: The IF function almost got it. Returned 10/2/2019 for the 13/10/19. Should have returned 10/13/2019.

Comment: The second solution return 10/19/2013 for 13/10/19.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tHknld_oc8Fw4kLFYycdmbTp8YJw4_nF/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106060891313761840163&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong considering your solution definitely works. I wasn't kidding when I said I was struggling. Thank you for taking the time to try to assist.

Comment: @Exalted_X My fault... Check updated formula... Should have been `=IF(ISNUMBER(A5),A5,DATE(2000+RIGHT(A5,2),MID(A5,4,2)+0,LEFT(A5,2)+0))`

Comment: Dude. You are freaking amazing.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I'd add another column to convert to epoch and back to new date format. https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-excel-date could help

Assuming the input is in A10:A11, I made for B10:

```
=((A10-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400/86400)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

and applied new date format to B:B.

Comment: How would that work? A bit confused